# How to get directory and file names while looping in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm doing a loop in files of directories and I need to get the current directory and file name on each step.

```
for f in /path/to/*/*.ext
do
  command "$d" "f" #! Here we send those two as parameters
done
```

I also need the file name without the extension ( .ext ). How should I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `basename` and `dirname`:

```
for f in /path/to/*/*.ext
do
  command "$(dirname "$f")" "$(basename "$f")" 
done
```

Another way using `awk` with `.ext` deletion:

```
for f in /path/to/*/*.ext ;do
   echo "$f"|awk -F\/ '{a=$NF;$NF="";gsub(".ext","",a)}{print $0" "a}' OFS=\/
done
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, use the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in /path/to/*/*.ext; do
    my_command "${f%/*}" "${f##*/}"
done
```

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

The `shopt -s nullglob` is highly recommended, so that the glob `/path/to/*/*.ext` expands to nothing (and hence the loop is not executed, so that `my_command` is not executed with the random verbatim arguments `/path/to/*` and `*.ext`) if there are no matches.